# Meaning of convexity in a graph

Tags: convex-analysis

A differentiable and also convex function has the following property.

$$
(\nabla f (x) - \nabla f (y))^T(x-y) \geq 0
$$

I can derive it from the first order condition for a convex function,

$$
f(y) \geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)
\\
f(x) \geq f(y)+\nabla f(y)^T(x-y)
$$

by adding the two inequalities and rearrange it.

but I don't know meanings of the inequality in a graph.

Does it mean that a tangent line should be above the graph? but how? or is something else?

Could you explain the meaning?

Comment: I believe your expression might be wrong. For a multivariate function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, the condition that for $n=1$ reads $f(x)\geq f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$ should for general $n\in \mathbb{N}$ read $f(x)\geq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T\cdot (x-y)$, and indeed the graph should lie above all its tangents, since otherwise the epigraph wouldn't be *convex*, that is, we could not connect any two points in the space $E$ "over the graph" with a segment whose points lie entirely inside $E$.

Comment: @Albert Yes, the graph should lie above all its tangents. I edited the question to correct the expression.

Comment: If you know that convexity implies the graph lies above its tangents, why do you explicitly ask whether the opposite is true? "Does it mean that a tanget line should be above the graph?"

Comment: For $n=1$ it means that $f'$ is monotoncally increasing.